# Css Drop down not working in FTL

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, wordpress, freemarker

Am using cssdropdown plugin in ftl file and it just didn't work with it.

I had the same code working fine in a jsp page.

My code is as follows,

```
   <div id="subMenu">
     <div class="drpdown posRel">
       <div class="tab" id="chromemenu">
      <span style="padding-right:1px;">
             <@s.a href="createMessage.action">&nbsp;Demo&nbsp;&nbsp;|</@s.a><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="dropmenu1" onclick="document.getElementById('dropmenu1').style.width =document.getElementById('dropmenu1').offsetWidth+'px';"> <img src="images/image.gif" /></a></span></div>
    <div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenudiv">                           <@s.a href="${stack.findValue('href')}" class="sample_attach"><span>&nbsp;${stack.findValue('label')}</span></@s.a>                              <@s.a href="${stack.findValue('href')}" class="sample_attach"><span>&nbsp;${stack.findValue('label')}</span></@s.a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">cssdropdown.startchrome("chromemenu")</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there any dependency i had to add for ftl.

P.S. I had an iterator that iterates the  in this code. I could see the HTML output same as of my jsp page but it is not working in ftl.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the HTML output... If it's identical to what the JSP outputs, then look closer, because the browser doesn't care if the HTML was generated by JSP, FTL or whatever, since both JSP and FTL runs on the server, not on the client.

Comment: Ya both runs on server. But the startchrome function is not getting trigered in Ftl, but it works fine on jsp pages.

Comment: Again, that can't be because of FTL, since JS runs on the client too. There must be some difference between the two HTML-s. (Or between the HTTP responses...)